# jquery plugin boilerplate element

Tags: jquery, boilerplate

I am trying to develop plugin using jquery-boilerplate-v3.1 and confused between "this" and "$(this)"

```
    in the plugin 
    ...
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    //alert($(this).toSource());
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
};
```

seems that the `new Plugin(this, options)` does not return the element inside Plugin.prototype context.

Instead, I've modified it to `Plugin($(this), options)`.

```
eg.
   $(function(){
     $('#container').myPlugin();
   });
```

without using $(this) as parameter, I cannot access this.element in the plugin, .toSource() return empty object `({})`.

Am I doing the correct way by modifying to $(this) or how can I access the #container with `this` parameter.

TIA.

Comment: Seems like there are a lot of "boilerplates" in this world. What I mentioned above was the plate that downloaded from [link]http://jqueryboilerplate.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the plugin, `this` refers to the jQuery object that you apply the plugin to, but inside the callback for `this.each()`, `this` refers to each single DOM element inside the jQuery object.

So, yes, you need `$(this)` to get a jQuery object containing that element inside the loop.